# How can multiple recaptchas attach to ng-repeat(ed) results?

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

JS Included:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit
```

AngularJS App:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      var items = {
        "lettuce": "2",
        "pear": "2",
        "orange": "3",
        "apple": "1",
        "grapes": "3",
        "banana": "2"
        };  
      $scope.items = items;
    }]);
```

Explicit ReCaptcha Callback:

```
var CaptchaCallback = function(){

    // BUG:
    // how do i make this run as a loop over all the "items" currently being returned from a webservice
    //  without having to specifically type 'captcha_lettuce' or 'captcha_pear' for the captcha to physically find/attach to that DOM element

    grecaptcha.render('captcha_lettuce', {'sitekey' : 'captcha-key-here'});
    grecaptcha.render('captcha_pear', {'sitekey' : 'captcha-key-here'});
    grecaptcha.render('captcha_orange', {'sitekey' : 'captcha-key-here'});
    grecaptcha.render('captcha_apple', {'sitekey' : 'captcha-key-here'});
    grecaptcha.render('captcha_grapes', {'sitekey' : 'captcha-key-here'});
    grecaptcha.render('captcha_banana', {'sitekey' : 'captcha-key-here'});
};
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">    

<h3>Items for Sale - Multiple forms</h3>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <div ng-repeat="(fruit,price) in items">

            {{fruit}}: ${{price}}<br/>

            First Name:<input type='text'/><br/>
            Last Name:<input type='text'/>
            <div id="captcha_{{fruit}}"></div>
            <input type='submit'/><br/><br/><br/>                

        </div>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom directive to call the `grecaptcha.render` function when`ng-repeat` creates the element on the DOM.

```
<div ng-repeat="(fruit,price) in items">
     <div id="captcha_{{fruit}}" my-directive></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          grecaptcha.render(attrs.id, {'sitekey' : 'captcha-key-here'});
        };    
    };
});
```

For more information visit [AngularJS Guide for Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).